# Select value that only occurs once

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn on how to select values that only occur once.

I would like to select the names of applicants who only have one and one only application.

```
SELECT name FROM (SELECT COUNT(anumber) AS count FROM APPLIES 
GROUP BY anumber HAVING (count = 1)) AS x;
```

Could you please assist me as I cannot figure out where I am going wrong with this, I am still new to using MySQL.

Comment: Please add sample data, what results or error your query is returning, and what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough. The output is all the names in table applies, that occur only once.

```
SELECT name FROM APPLIES 
GROUP BY anumber
having count(anumber) = 1;
```

EDIT: 
Looking at your query, you are trying to select a name from this subquery, that only has a "count":

```
SELECT COUNT(anumber) AS count FROM APPLIES 
GROUP BY anumber HAVING (count = 1)
```

Comment: Your query will fail for `HAVING count(*) = 1` . It should be `HAVING count(anumber)` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
SELCT name FROM APPLIES
GROUP BY anumber
HAVING COUNT(anumber)=1
```

This should get you the names that have exactly one `anumber` (I am assuming anumber means application number here)

Here's a link explaining different use cases of GROUP BY and HAVING which you can refer to if you want something else - https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-having.php